# method (XSLT) to group nodes per father element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, nodes

I would like to group nodes per father elements.

Here the **father element** is :       **FDDCell id="AAA"  method="modify"**

- The father element is repeated two times.
- I would like "FDDCell id" to appear only one time. and group all the nodes under "FDDCell id"

Here is the XML input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<start>

<FDDCell id="AAA"  method="modify">
<UMTSFddNeighbouringCell id="FAR_AWAY" method="create">
    <attributes>
        <mbmsNeighbouringWeight>0.0</mbmsNeighbouringWeight>
    </attributes>
</UMTSFddNeighbouringCell>
</FDDCell>

<FDDCell id="AAA" method="modify">
<attributes>
    <cacConfId>RadioAccessService/0 DedicatedConf/0 CacConfClass/10</cacConfId>
    <layerPreferredForR99>true</layerPreferredForR99>
    <reserved0>1398341632</reserved0>
    <reserved1>1398352896</reserved1>
    <reserved2>1616994144</reserved2>
    <reserved3>1616994144</reserved3>
</attributes>
</FDDCell>

</start>
```

Here is the output file desired:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <start>

 <FDDCell id="AAA" method="modify">
  <UMTSFddNeighbouringCell id="FAR_AWAY" method="create">
    <attributes>
        <mbmsNeighbouringWeight>0.0</mbmsNeighbouringWeight>
    </attributes>
 </UMTSFddNeighbouringCell>

<attributes>
    <cacConfId>RadioAccessService/0 DedicatedConf/0 CacConfClass/10</cacConfId>
    <layerPreferredForR99>true</layerPreferredForR99>
    <reserved0>1398341632</reserved0>
    <reserved1>1398352896</reserved1>
    <reserved2>1616994144</reserved2>
    <reserved3>1616994144</reserved3>
</attributes>

</FDDCell>
</start>
```

thanks so much for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="start">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="FDDCell" group-by="@id">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, current-group()/node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can run that with XSLT 2.0 processors like Saxon 9, AltovaXML tools, XMLPrime.